# I need the white pieces to be on top of the road, not behind it

Tags: unity-game-engine

First, I add lanes to the stage, and then through Update my cars move to the left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj4GE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgjnv.png)

Comment: Post also...your transform hierarchy, the code that spawns these objects, and the manner in which they are drawn (3D, 2D, OnGui, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a multiple things.

The [render queue](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.RenderQueue.html) on the objects behind the road being lower than the render queue of the road. the highest render queue will always be drawn on top.

The order in which you render your objects. If you look at your hierarchy the items that are lowest in the hierarchy will be drawn latest, and thus on top if the render queue is the same. see example [here](https://gyazo.com/0926f118b30ff6d374d0f1946074dff7) `Background image` is on top of `item in front of background` in the hierarchy, meaning it will be drawn before `item in front of background`. So when `Item in front of background` gets drawn it will be on top of `background image`

If you are using seperate [canvasses](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.html) for your road and cars see if the `SortOrder` is set correctly. higher sort order means it will be displayed before lower sort order

Comment: simply change the order by dragging the item you want to see on top in your view to the bottom of your hierachy (click and drag the object you want to change the order of inside your hierarchy)

Comment: everything is generated automatically: first the road, then the cars

Comment: Change the order in which it is generated. Order of generating equals order in hiararchy. Can you post the code snippet in which you generate it?

Comment: If you post the code in which you generate the objects maybe i can see where the issue is.